# Cell Value Comparisons To Min/Max Cell Values And Write P Or F To Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare Measurement Value in one cell to Min Limits in another cell. Same with comparison to cell with Max Limits using variables. If measurement value is with limits, need to write "P" or "F" into 4th cell as results of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If your Min was in B1 and your Max in B2 and the value to be tested was in A1:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=B1,A1<=B2),"P","F")
```